# Why does this threaded code not print anything?

Tags: java, multithreading

can someone tell me what is wrong with here? It does not print out anything.

```
public class thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread mythread = new Thread();
    mythread.start();
    Thread mythread1 = new Thread();
    mythread1.start();

}
    public class mythread extends Thread{
        int i;
        public void run() {
            for(i = 0; i<10;i++)
                System.out.println(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It can´t print anything if you never create an instance of it..

Comment: everything is wrong there....

Comment: Also, start your class names with a capital letter.

Comment: You're not creating instances of your `mythread` class.  Among other issues...

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy if he creates instance of mythread then the run method will be executed. Thread implements Runnable.

Comment: @Sneh ah yeah my bad removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that:

1. Classes always start with capital letter (for example `MyThread`) and every following words starts with capital too (so 'my thread' -> `class MyThread`)
2. Name your classes, where you use main' accordingly, for example my colleges use `class Main` or `class ProjectRun` etc.. Naming should always make sense.
3. When you are implementing a method from your parent, always use `@Override` annotation (like you can see in my code below).

Here's some code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread myThread1 = new Main.MyThread();
        myThread1.run();
        Thread myThread2 = new Main.MyThread();
        myThread2.run();
    }

    public static class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for( int i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling the run methods of the threads is _not_ what the OP was trying to accomplish.  I assume you mean start, right?

Comment: Re, "Classes always start with capital letter."  That's by convention.  The Java language does not require it.  Your class names _should_ always start with a capital letter if you're going to ask other Java programmers to read and comment on your code.

Comment: @Gray Yes, I meant that! I was just trying to 'fix' his way of approach. But you are right, I should be more careful about the answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Your classname should start with a capital (read the [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)).
- You should not name your classes the same as Java classes.
- You should name your own class MyThread. (Or better yet, name it something descriptive, like CounterRunnable/CounterThread)
- Instantiate MyThread instead of java.lang.Thread .
- It's better to implement a Runnable than to extend Thread.

Edit: And a nitpick: a nice descriptive title on your post on StackOverflow wouldn't hurt either. You probably can do better than "Please help, does not work".

Comment: can't understand its very difficult

Comment: The compiler says: "Error:(3, 29) non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context". This means that you try to instantiate Mythread from a static context, but the inner class is not static. Either make that static, or better yet, move the inner class to a file of it own.

Comment: thank you. I got it

Comment: class Mythread extends Thread{
 
 public void run() {
  for(int i = 0; i<10;i++) {
   System.out.println(i);
 }
 
}
}

public class thread {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Mythread mythread = new Mythread();
 mythread.start();
 Mythread mythread1 = new Mythread();
 mythread1.start();

 }

}

Answer (score 0):

> can someone tell me what is wrong with here? It does not print out anything.

The problem with your code is that you are calling:

```
Thread mythread = new Thread();
```

Instead you should:

```
Thread mythread = new mythread();
```

You are forking a thread which doesn't do anything because the default `run()` method of a thread is just a no-op.  If you instantiate and start your `mythread` class instead then your `run()` method will be executed.

As mentioned by others, you should also consider the following improvements:

- Java class names are typically capitalized to distinguish them from fields or variable names.  So you should use `MyThread`.
- It is a recommended that your class should implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.
- You should always try to limit the scope of a variable so don't use a field `int i` but instead do `for (int i = 0 ...`.

So your code really should be:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
...
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         System.out.println(i);
      }
   }
}
```